# как я могу получить имя учетной записи Google

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, google-calendar

как я могу получить имя учетной записи Google на Android-смартфоне с помощью скрипта python. для автоввода в сообщение телеграм.
я создал телеграм бота. этот бот записывает клиента на сеанс массажа. я хочу, чтобы в моей учетной записи было автоматически создано событие, и я хочу поделиться этим событием с клиентом. для того что бы напоминание срабатывало у клиента

Comment: а где работает скрипт?

Comment: есть телеграм бот он на сервере, нужен способ получения имени гугл аккаунта со стороны пользователя. т.е пользователь заходит в телеграм бот и нажимает на кнопку и его имя аккаунта вписывается в поле для ввода текста в телеграме

Comment: слабо представляю возможный механизм. Во-первых, у телеграма должен быть тогда доступ к учетным записям на телефоне. Это вряд ли у него есть. Во-вторых, что делать, если на телефоне две и больше учеток гугла?